# Obfuscate HTA files

Tags: obfuscation, hta

The heading says it all. I have HTA files and I need to obfuscate them. There is no legal implication but i have a dangerous customer who can tweak the code and create havoc.

Comment: If code is to be executed client-side, then there is no robust way of preventing a dedicated hacker from reverse-engineering your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can compress and obfuscate the JavaScript using one of the [many JavaScript compressors](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=javascript+compressor). This won't prevent any determined attack on the code, but may prevent casual tweaking.

Comment: thanks Sky. Compressor is one option we looked at but it doesn't really obfuscate just makes it hard to read. Modern IDEs can reformat back.

Comment: Many compressors will rename variables and sometimes functions to just a few letters, which can make the code harder to read when everything is like `a=b[f][s].gg(z);`. You could look into running all your strings through ROT13 as well, I don't know of a compressor that does that automatically though. You may want to look at [Google Closure Compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/), which is about as close to a compiler for JavaScript as you will get.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use Microsoft Script Encoder for this purpose:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?DisplayLang=en&id=3375

Use it like this:

```
"Screnc /e htm test.hta test-encrypted.hta"
```

Make sure you don't forget to mark the .HTA-file with the start encoding tag:

```
'**Start Encode**
```

Answer (score 1):

Our [JavaScript obfuscator](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Obfuscators/ECMAScriptObfuscator.html) renames identifiers, strips comments and formatting, and can encrypt string literals.

As everyone points out, yes, a determined reverse engineer can do so, but the point is he really has to make an effort.   If the application is big, he has to make a correspondingly big effort.

The link addresses why the Microsoft script encoder is a bad idea.